# Where are responses to a video listed on YouTube?

Tags: youtube

In the new skin I can't find out where video responses to a video are listed, nor which video a video is in response to. Is the information still available, or did Google forget about it in the redesign?

Comment: Are these video responses to videos on your account or videos in general ?

Comment: Videos in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a panel below the video containing all video responses, including a link to the video it's a response to.

[image: Video responses]

To find out whether a video really has responses, go to:

> http://www.youtube.com/video_response_view_all?v=**vidid**

Replace **vidid** with the video's id. If there aren't any video responses, you'll get an error message telling you this.

Comment: Ah, it's hiding below the uploader and highest rated comments.